# HttpSession attribute getting removed abnormally after adding

Tags: spring, session, attributes

```
*After I add a session attribute using 
    WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, VBWebConstants.SESSION_ORDER_BEAN,sellerDetails);

    @RequestMapping(value="/minasidor/step1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView step1(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session){
            if(logger.isTraceEnabled())logger.trace("VbSellerController ::: step1 ::: start");
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled())logger.debug("[Order Step1] [Start]");
            ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("vz-new/mina-sidor/v-orderstep1");
            LoginBean user = (LoginBean) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, VBWebConstants.SESSION_USER);
            mav.addObject("submenu",3);
            if(!checkOrderLifeCycle()){
                mav.addObject("orderNotAllowed", false);
                return mav;
            }
            try{
                String orderValue = "";
                orderValue =  InMemoryCache.getCaProperty(PropertyEnum.MIN_ORDER_VALUE.getDatabasekey());
                int minimumOrderValue = CawebUtil.isInt(orderValue);

            CpSellerDetails sellerDetails=vbOrderService.getStep1Data(user.getGrp_seller_id(),user.getCatalogue_id());
            if(sellerDetails != null){
                mav.addObject("productlist",sellerDetails.getSellerList());
                mav.addObject("totalValue",sellerDetails.getTotalOrderValue());
                mav.addObject("allowedfororder",sellerDetails.getTotalOrderValue() > minimumOrderValue);
                // mav addobject add discount details    Discount Object ArrayList  
                WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, VBWebConstants.SESSION_ORDER_STEP_COMPLETED,"step1");
                WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, VBWebConstants.SESSION_ORDER_BEAN,sellerDetails);
            }else{
                mav.addObject("allowedfororder",false);
                WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, VBWebConstants.SESSION_ORDER_STEP_COMPLETED,null);
            }


        }catch(DataNotFoundException e){
            logger.trace("Exception in retrieving data for step1",e);
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled())logger.debug("[Order Step1 Exception]",e);
        }
        if(logger.isTraceEnabled())logger.trace("VbSellerController ::: step1 ::: end");
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())logger.debug("[Order Step1] [end]");
        return mav;
    }
Within this step1 method the VBWebConstants.SESSION_ORDER_BEAN session attribute is getting removed instantly after the step1() method finishes executing where as the other session attributes remains the same.When i debug the below Http Listener class 
    public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener,HttpSessionAttributeListener {



    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyHttpSessionListener.class);
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        //String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sbuilder.append("\n").append("-----------     Session Created    -------------- ");
            Enumeration<String> sessionAttrs = session.getAttributeNames();
            while (sessionAttrs.hasMoreElements()) {
                String name =  sessionAttrs.nextElement();
                sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session created ").append(name); 
            }
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  created time "+ CawebUtil.getTimeStampInString(new Timestamp(session.getCreationTime())));
            sbuilder.append("\n").append("---------------------------------------------------- ").append("\n");
            logger.debug(sbuilder.toString());
        }
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            try{
                String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
                logger.debug(" session destroyed " +ipAddr);
            }catch (Exception e) {              
            }
        }

    }
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {
        String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sbuilder.append("\n").append("-----------     Attribute added   -------------- from ").append(ipAddr);
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  max inactive time "+ session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  id "+ session.getId());
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  attribute added "+ se.getName()).append("  =  ").append(se.getValue());
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  created time "+ CawebUtil.getTimeStampInString(new Timestamp(session.getCreationTime())));
        }

    }
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled() ){
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sbuilder.append("\n").append("-----------     Attribute removed   -------------- from ");//.append(ipAddr);
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  attribute removed "+ se.getName()).append("  =  ").append(se.getValue());

        }
    }
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sbuilder.append("\n").append("-----------     Attribute replaced   -------------- from ");//.append(ipAddr);
            sbuilder.append("\n").append(" session  attribute "+ se.getName()).append("  =  ").append(se.getValue());
        }
    }
    }
I found that the session attribute is getting removed.Checked through the entire code I couldn't find what's the reason...???
```

Here is the CPSellerDetails class which i try to add to the session there are other 2 session attributes among which one is a string object and other is a bean.could it the size of the class that is the cause for session attribute being removed abnormally

```
public class CpSellerDetails implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4627284179051380310L;
    private List<SellerProduct>  sellerList ;
    private float totalOrderValue ;
    private VbCpInfoBean cpinfoBean;
    private Integer orderno;
    private float invoiceAmount;
    private Date orderedDate;
    private ArrayList<DiscountVO> discounts;
    private Address billingInfo;

    public VbCpInfoBean getCpInfoBean() {
        return cpinfoBean;
    }
    public void setCpInfoBean(VbCpInfoBean infoBean) {
        this.cpinfoBean = infoBean;
    }
    public List<SellerProduct> getSellerList() {
        return sellerList;
    }
    public void setSellerList(List<SellerProduct> sellerList) {
        this.sellerList = sellerList;
    }
    public float getTotalOrderValue() {
        return totalOrderValue;
    }
    public void setTotalOrderValue(float totalOrderValue) {
        this.totalOrderValue = totalOrderValue;
    }
    public float getInvoiceAmount() {
        return invoiceAmount;
    }
    public void setInvoiceAmount(float invoiceAmount) {
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
    }
    public Integer getOrderno() {
        return orderno;
    }
    public void setOrderno(Integer orderno) {
        this.orderno = orderno;
    }
    public Date getOrderedDate() {
        return orderedDate;
    }
    public void setOrderedDate(Date orderedDate) {
        this.orderedDate = orderedDate;
    }
    public ArrayList<DiscountVO> getDiscounts() {
        return discounts;
    }
    public void setDiscounts(ArrayList<DiscountVO> discounts) {
        this.discounts = discounts;
    }

    public Address getBillingInfo() {
        return billingInfo;
    }
    public void setBillingInfo(Address billingInfo) {
        this.billingInfo = billingInfo;
    }


}*
```

Comment: Could you please post the `sellerDetails` class.

Comment: I have posted the SellerDetails class...!

Comment: Is every referenced object of `CpSellerDetails` serializeable?

Comment: Have you ever set a breakpoint in your SessionListener to get an clue where the remove "invocation" come from?

Comment: The data members in CpSellerDetails are not all serializable and the remove invocation is automatically done whenever the step1() method finishes execution but within the method i can see that is set to the session by using WebUtils getSessionAttribute but once the method finishes execution it is being removed.Do all the data members including User defined beans need to be serializable ???

Comment: Every thing that is store in a session, should be serializable.

Comment: Before this the data members in CpSellerDetails are not all serializable and now i have made all of those serializable but still the same thing repeats.Could the size of the object be the reason for it being removed.I have checked if anything is intercepting in the middle but clueless

Comment: It was an interceptor that i didn't notice that's causing the heck.I found it and fixed